# Access iterate object in jsp using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In my JSP page, it has the following:

```
<logic:present name="addrObj">
   <logic:iterate id="address" name="addrObj">  
    <tr>
       <td width="50%" valign="top" bgcolor="#C9C9C9">
         <logic:present  name="address" property="street">
            <span class="mediumBlackBold"><b>
            <jsp:getProperty name="address" property="street" />
            </b></span>
         </logic:present>
   </td>
   <td valign="top" bgcolor="#EEE5DE">
     <logic:present  name="address" property="city">
        <span class="mediumBlack">
        <jsp:getProperty name="address" property="city" />
        </span><br />
     </logic:present>
   </td>
   </tr>
 </logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
```

address is an object contains street and city elements. If I need to update the street and city information when the page is loaded, how can I access the address object to update the information using JQuery?

Comment: There is nothing to do with jQuery to populate the page. It is enough to logic iterate and bean tags. use `<bean:write name="address" property="street" />` for display your values. Please change jQuery tag to Struts tag.

Comment: The street/city value will be derived by js or jQuery dynamically. <bean:write> doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Can you show me your js/jQuery, what you are doing while page load?